# deep $watch on objects array returning Illegal invocation

Tags: angularjs, arrays, watch

I have a directive and i am trying to watch one of scope's members, an array of objects.

```
        <div ng-repeat="image in images track by $index" class="cr-form image-block-holder clearfix">
            <div ng-class="images[$index].imageFile == undefined ? 'image-upload' : 'image-upload image-active'">
                <div class="cr-file-upload" style="position: relative">
                    <input id="crChooseFile" type="file" ngf-select ng-model="images[$index].imageFile" ngf-multiple="false" ng-attr-accept="image/*" 
                           class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="uploadField" image="imageFile" />

                </div>
                <div class="cr-edit-business-profile">
                    <div class="cr-business-logo">
                        <img class="cr-profile-logo-img" ng-show="images[$index].imageFile" ng-src="{{images[$index].imageFile.url}}" type="{{images[$index].imageFile.file.type}}" />
                        <img ng-show="images[$index].imageFile == null && images[$index].logo" ng-src="{{images[$index].logo}}" type="image/png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-label">
                    <label>Browse</label> <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-elements">
                <div class="input-inner">
                    <textarea type="text" ng-model="images[$index].caption" ng-keyup="setCaption($index)" placeholder="Add Caption"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the watch in my directive:

```
                scope.$watch(function () { return scope.images }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue && oldValue) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            var changedIndex = -1;
                            for (var i = 0; i < scope.content.noOfImages && changedIndex == -1; i++) {
                                if (isDifferentImage(newValue[i].imageFile, oldValue[i].imageFile))
                                    changedIndex = i;
                            }
                            if (changedIndex == -1)
                                return;
                            scope.content.images[changedIndex].photo = newValue[changedIndex].imageFile;

                        }, 0, false);
                    }
                }, true);
```

I also tried with watchCollection, it does not get fired, without deep watch it does not get fired either. ng-change event does not seem to do the trick; deep $watch on objects array is returning Illegal invocation.

Any idea how to make this work? I am using angular 1.4.5

Comment: Can you post a plunker or example?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `$watch` only works well with JavaScript objects, arrays, strings, and primitives. When the contents includes special objects such as DOM elements, blobs, files, events, etc., it gets problematic

Comment: sorry, i'll keep that in mind next time, you are right, thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `images` array contains `File` objects.

The following can be found in the [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) documentation:

> This should not be used to watch for changes in objects that are or
>   contain File objects due to limitations with angular.copy.

You will have to solve it another way.

For example watching an array of file names instead (or `name` + `lastModified` if `name` is not enough for your use case):

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.files.map(function(file) {
    return file && file.name;
  });
}, function() {

  // Code

}, true);
```

Have seen the following in use as well:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return JSON.stringify($scope.files);
}, function() {

  // Code

});
```